# jQuery Mobile Form: Added fields aren't styled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am a total newbie to JavaScript and jQueryMobile, so please go easy on me (: I am building a budgeting app for a school project. It takes a user's income, multiplies it by the frequency of the paycheck, saves it to local storage, and updates it at the top of the page.

My problem is that I have the "add another" button, which allows the user to add a second source of income. However, for some reason, the user-added fields are not picking up the jQuery Mobile styles.

Here is the page: http://home.ubalt.edu/students/id59wk98/idia616/app-new/income.html. Click "add more" to see the newly added form fields, which aren't showing the jQuery Mobile styles.

The usrAdded div is where the new fields are plopped in, above the Update button. Here's the HTML.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">  
    <div id="usrAdded"></div>
        <div style="width:50%;">
            <input type="button" value="Update" id="paycheckButton" />
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <div style="width:50%;">
        <input type="button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon" id="addMoreButton" value="Add Another<br/>Source of Income">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript associated with the add more button.

```
window.onload = function() 
{ 
var moreButton = document.getElementById("addMoreButton");
moreButton.onclick = moreIncome; 
}

function moreIncome()
{
var incomeForm = document.getElementById("usrAdded");
var newLabel = document.createElement("select");
var payPeriod1 = document.createElement("option");
var payPeriod2 = document.createElement("option");
var payPeriod3 = document.createElement("option");
var newValue = document.createElement("input");
var spacer = document.createElement("br");
var newFieldLabel1 = document.createElement("label");
var newFieldLabel2 = document.createElement("label");

newLabel.setAttribute("type", "text");
newLabel.setAttribute("class", "usrIncome");

newValue.setAttribute("type", "number");
newValue.setAttribute("class", "incomeAmount");
newValue.setAttribute("default", "0");

payPeriod1.setAttribute("value", "weekly");
payPeriod2.setAttribute("value", "biweekly");
payPeriod3.setAttribute("value", "monthly");

incomeForm.appendChild(newFieldLabel1);
newFieldLabel1.innerHTML = "How often are you paid?";
incomeForm.appendChild(newLabel);
newLabel.appendChild(payPeriod1);
payPeriod1.innerHTML = "Every Week";
newLabel.appendChild(payPeriod2);
payPeriod2.innerHTML = "Every 2 Weeks";
newLabel.appendChild(payPeriod3);
payPeriod3.innerHTML = "Monthly";
incomeForm.appendChild(newFieldLabel2);
newFieldLabel2.innerHTML = "How much do you earn each paycheck?";
incomeForm.appendChild(newValue);       
}
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Omar's Answer below is correct. You have done your form using  Javascript but you need some Jquery to Enhance it as per JQM docs-- Demo with your form -- http://jsfiddle.net/3jfd4fqe/  -- see enhancewithin docs also for alternative method from Javascript --- http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/

Comment: Thank you both! It was very helpful to see the jsfiddle to understand what needed to change in my code and where. I had Googled enhanceWithin but wasn't sure where it belonged in the code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to enhance those elements manually.

```
$("#incomeForm").enhanceWithin();
```